# Changing the color of checkmark inside ion-checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, ionic-framework, colors, less

I'm tring to change the color of the checkmark inside the ion-checkbox. The checkbox has a white background and the the checkmark is white Im tring to get the checkmark to be black not white. This is what I have so far

```css
.checkbox-icon::before {
  background-color: white !important;
 
}

.checkbox-icon::after {
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
      <ion-item ng-repeat="list in modal.item.modifier_lists | orderBy: 'ordinal'"
                ng-if="list.modifier_options[0].name">
        <div ng-if="list.modifier_options.length === 1"
               class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ion-checkbox ng-model="list.modifier_options[0].selected"
                          ng-checked="list.modifier_options[0].selected"
                          class="button-orange checkbox-stable">
              <span class="pull-right">{{list.modifier_options[0].name}}</span>
            </ion-checkbox>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
```

Comment: per https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/ you change `border-color` on `.checkbox-inner`

Comment: `.checkbox-inner ` do I have to add this class to the html or is it built in class for  ion-checkbox  @MichaelCoker

Comment: Sorry man, I dunno. I've never used ionic. If you had a working demo where the checkbox renders, I could tell you what CSS to change. So I went to the ionic website to see if they had a demo. Best I can do :)

Answer (score 5):

Some of the css- properties you can use to change the coloring of the `<ion-checkbox>` are

```
  --checkmark-color: black;
  --background-checked: white;
  --border-color: black;
  --border-color-checked: black;
```

You can find more information in the [ion-checkbox documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox)

Comment: In new ionic version specially ionic 7   --background-checked: white; is not working 
  try --checkbox-background-checked: white; instead

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you actually have to use `border-color` to adjust the checkmark color

So to clarify here is what you could do:

Inside your `<ion-checkbox>` add a custom class of your own `custom-checkbox` and then for that class do whats below:

```
.custom-checkbox .checkbox-icon:after {
    border-color: //whatever you like it to be
}
```

That will change the color of the check mark when it is checked.

Comment: where do I add `border-color` inside the .checkbox-icon:before or .checkbox-icon:after or a new class  @joshsisley

Comment: I just edited my answer above with a solution that should work for you